# Upload Progress when upload multiple files

Tags: php, ajax, upload, progress-bar, ajaxsubmit

I want to upload multi-file (more than 1000 files, with total more than 2GB).
In PHP, i use function

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $original_file))
                    {
                        $stamp = '../contents/wm_watermark.png';
                        $this->create_watermark_photo($original_file, $stamp, $view_file, $ext);
                        $this->makeThumbnail($view_file, $thumb_file, $this->max_width_thumb, $this->max_width_thumb);

                        //insert photo info to DB
                        $this->Photo->create();
                        $this->Photo->save(
                            array(
                                'Photo' =>  array(
                                    'folder_id' =>  $data_from_preparing_fileInfoList[$i]['sub'],
                                    'name'      =>  $filename
                                )
                            )
                        );

                        $status = '1';
                        $count++;
                    }
```

I found out that, when use move_upload_file , it didn't upload right now. It only keep in waiting stack. When this function run completedly, then it move file to server.
So, when i use upload process, it gain 100% , this ajax url still run.

```
$("#image_upload_form").ajaxSubmit({
                    //url: '/admin/photoGroup/ajax_upload_photo', //photo upload process bar
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { data_from_preparing: data_from_preparing},
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        //dialog 1
                        $("#upload-photo-process .progress-bar").css('width', '0');
                        $('#upload-photo-process').modal('show');

                    },
                    /* progress bar call back*/
                    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                        console.log('percentComplete' + percentComplete);
                        console.log('position: ' + position);
                        console.log('total' + total);
                        var mbPosition = position / 1024 / 1024;
                        var mbTotal = total / 1024 / 1024;
                        var txtProcess = percentComplete + '% | ' + mbPosition + 'Mb/' + mbTotal + 'Mb';
                        var pVel = percentComplete + '%';
                        $("#upload-photo-process .process-status").html(txtProcess);

                        $("#upload-photo-process .progress-bar").css('width', pVel);

                    },

                    /* complete call back */
                    complete: function(xhr) {
                        if (xhr.statusText == "OK") {
                            $('#upload-photo-process').modal('hide');
                            $('#upload-done').modal('show');
                        }

                    }
                    /*success: function(data_from_photo_upload) {

                    }*/

                });
```

[image]

Now, i want to when upload progress gain 100%, all of files uploaded to server.
How do i can that?
Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

try this it may work..

```js
   //attach
  function sendFileToServer(formData, status, file) {
    var uploadURL = "index.php?p=ticket-attach&ajax=1"; //Upload URL
    var extraData = {}; //Extra Data.
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
      xhr: function() {
        var xhrobj = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (xhrobj.upload) {
          xhrobj.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
            var percent = 0;
            var position = event.loaded || event.position;
            var total = event.total;
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
              percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
            }
            //Set progress
            status.setProgress(percent);
          }, false);
        }
        return xhrobj;
      },
      url: uploadURL,
      type: "POST",
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      cache: false,
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        if (data['error'] == "") {
          status.setProgress(100);
          status.setFileNameSize(data['fname'].split(",")[0], file.size);
          status.appendFN(data['fname']);
          //var namef= ;
        } else {
          //alert(data['error']);
          status.errorMsg();
        }
      }
    });
    status.setAbort(jqXHR);
  }

  function createStatusbar(obj) {
    this.statusbar = $("<div class='statusbar'  id=''></div>");
    this.filename = $("<div class='filename'></div>").appendTo(this.statusbar);
    this.size = $("<div class='filesize'></div>").appendTo(this.statusbar);
    this.abort = $("<div class='abort'>&times;</div>").appendTo(this.statusbar);
    this.progressBar = $("<div class='progressBar'><div></div></div>").appendTo(this.statusbar);
    obj.append(this.statusbar);
    this.setFileNameSize = function(name, size) {
      var sizeStr = "";
      var sizeKB = size / 1024;
      if (parseInt(sizeKB) > 1024) {
        var sizeMB = sizeKB / 1024;
        sizeStr = sizeMB.toFixed(2) + " MB";
      } else {
        sizeStr = sizeKB.toFixed(2) + " KB";
      }
      this.filename.html(name);
      this.size.html("(" + sizeStr + ")");
      this.statusbar.attr("sizev", size);
      $("#attach_size").attr("sizev", parseInt($("#attach_size").attr("sizev")) + size);
      this.setTotalSize();
    }
    this.setTotalSize = function() {
      //set total size
      var size = parseInt($("#attach_size").attr("sizev"));

      var sizeStr = "";
      var sizeKB = size / 1024;
      if (parseInt(sizeKB) > 1024) {
        var sizeMB = sizeKB / 1024;
        sizeStr = sizeMB.toFixed(2) + " MB";
      } else {
        sizeStr = sizeKB.toFixed(2) + " KB";
      }
      if (sizeStr != "" && size > 0) $("#attach_size").html("(" + sizeStr + ")");
      else $("#attach_size").html("");
    }
    this.setProgress = function(progress) {

      var progressBarWidth = progress * this.progressBar.width() / 100;
      this.progressBar.find('div').animate({
        width: progressBarWidth
      }, 10).html(progress + "%");
      if (parseInt(progress) >= 100) {
        this.progressBar.hide();
        if ($.isFunction(tinymce.get)) tinymce.get('mail_body').isNotDirty = 0;
        $("#save_status").html("Not saved");

        //this.abort.hide();
      } else {
        if ($.isFunction(tinymce.get)) tinymce.get('mail_body').isNotDirty = 1;
        $("#save_status").html("Not saved");
      }
    }
    this.setAbortFD = function() {
      var sb = this.statusbar;
      var ts = this;
      this.abort.click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "index.php?p=ticket-dattach&ajax=1",
          data: "fname=" + sb.children(".filename").children("input").val(),
          //dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            tinymce.get('mail_body').isNotDirty = 0;
            $("#save_status").html("Not saved");
          },
          error: function() {
            alert('File is not deleted');
          }
        });
        //alert(sb.children(".filename").children("input").val());
        $("#attach_size").attr("sizev", (parseInt($("#attach_size").attr("sizev")) - parseInt(sb.attr("sizev"))));
        sb.remove();
        ts.setTotalSize();
      });
    }
    this.setAbort = function(jqxhr) {
      var sb = this.statusbar;
      var ts = this;
      this.abort.click(function() {
        jqxhr.abort();
        if (sb.children(".progressBar").children("div").html() == "100%") {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php?p=ticket-dattach&ajax=1",
            data: "fname=" + sb.children(".filename").children("input").val(),
            //dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
              tinymce.get('mail_body').isNotDirty = 0;
              $("#save_status").html("Not saved");
            },
            error: function() {
              alert('File is not deleted');
            }
          });
          $("#attach_size").attr("sizev", (parseInt($("#attach_size").attr("sizev")) - parseInt(sb.attr("sizev"))));
          sb.remove();
        } else {
          sb.remove();
        }
        ts.setTotalSize();
      });
    }
    this.appendFN = function(fn) {
      this.filename.append("<input type=\"hidden\"  name=\"ticket_attach[]\"  value=\"" + fn + "\"   />");
    }
    this.errorMsg = function() {
      var sb = this.statusbar;
      sb.children(".progressBar").children("div").html("File Error");
      sb.children(".progressBar").show();
      sb.children(".filename").children("input").remove()
    }
  }

  function toggle_class(clas) {
    $("." + clas).toggle();
  }

  function insert_attach(input) {
    var files = input.files;
    $.each(files, function(idx, file) {
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('ticket_attach', file);
      var obj = $(".note-attachbox");
      var status = new createStatusbar(obj); //Using this we can set progress.
      status.setFileNameSize(file.name, file.size);
      sendFileToServer(fd, status, file);
    });
    $("#afile_browser").val("");
  }
```

```css
.abort {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="note-attachbox" id="attachbox" style="position: relative; display: inline;"></div>
<input type='file' id='afile_browser' onchange='return insert_attach(this);' style="opacity: 0; position: relative; display: inline; cursor: pointer; width: 100px; padding: 1px 0px; border: medium none;" multiple>
<div style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(59, 179, 36); display: inline-block; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; vertical-align: middle; background: none; width: auto; padding: 5px 0px; margin-left: -105px;">+<i style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: normal;">Attach files<span id="attach_size" sizev="0"></span ></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That result must not be my need.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can follow the below approach to get it done.

I have try my best to make the example as simple as possible.

You need to implement this approach in your code to reach the result.

**The below code is working and tested.**

**Users**

Contains user details username, password, email, profile_image and profile_image_small etc.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`user_id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`username` varchar(255) UNIQUE KEY,
`password` varchar(100),
`email` varchar(255) UNIQUE KEY
)
```

**User Uploads**

Contains user upload details upload_id, image_name, user_id_fk(foreign key) and timestamp etc.

```
CREATE TABLE  `user_uploads` (
`upload_id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`image_name` text,
`user_id_fk` int(11),
`created` int(11)
)
```

**Javascript Code**

$("#photoimg").live('change',function(){})- photoimg is the ID name of INPUT FILE tag and $('#imageform').ajaxForm() - imageform is the ID name of FORM. While changing INPUT it calls FORM submit without refreshing page using ajaxForm() method. Uploaded images will prepend inside #preview tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.wallform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

$('#photoimg').live('change', function()
 {
var A=$("#imageloadstatus");
var B=$("#imageloadbutton");

$("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview',
beforeSubmit:function(){
A.show();
B.hide();
},
success:function(){
A.hide();
B.show();
},
error:function(){
A.hide();
B.show();
} }).submit();
});

});
</script>
```

Here hiding and showing #imageloadstatus and #imageloadbutton based on form upload submit status.

**index.php**

Contains simple PHP and HTML code. Here $session_id=1 means user id session value.

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();
$session_id='1'; // User login session value
?>
<div id='preview'>
</div>
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaxImageUpload.php' style="clear:both">
Upload image: 
<div id='imageloadstatus' style='display:none'><img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/></div>
<div id='imageloadbutton'>
<input type="file" name="photos[]" id="photoimg" multiple="true" />
</div>
</form>
```

**ajaxImageUpload.php**

Contains PHP code. This script helps you to upload images into uploads folder and it will  rename image file into timestamp+session_id.extention format to avoid duplicates. This system will store image files into user_uploads with user session id tables

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include('db.php');
$session_id='1'; //$session id
define ("MAX_SIZE","2000"); // 2MB MAX file size
function getExtension($str)
{
$i = strrpos($str,".");
if (!$i) { return ""; }
$l = strlen($str) - $i;
$ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
return $ext;
}
// Valid image formats 
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
$uploaddir = "uploads/"; //Image upload directory
foreach ($_FILES['photos']['name'] as $name => $value)
{
$filename = stripslashes($_FILES['photos']['name'][$name]);
$size=filesize($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name]);
//Convert extension into a lower case format
$ext = getExtension($filename);
$ext = strtolower($ext);
//File extension check
if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
{
//File size check
if ($size < (MAX_SIZE*1024))
{
$image_name=time().$filename;
echo "<img src='".$uploaddir.$image_name."' class='imgList'>";
$newname=$uploaddir.$image_name;
//Moving file to uploads folder
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name], $newname))
{
$time=time();
//Insert upload image files names into user_uploads table
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_uploads(image_name,user_id_fk,created) VALUES('$image_name','$session_id','$time')");
}
else
{
echo '<span class="imgList">You have exceeded the size limit! so moving unsuccessful! </span>'; }
}

else
{
echo '<span class="imgList">You have exceeded the size limit!</span>';
}

}

else
{
echo '<span class="imgList">Unknown extension!</span>';
}

} //foreach end

}
?>
```

**db.php**

Database configuration file, just modify database credentials.

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "username";
$mysql_password = "password";
$mysql_database = "database";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
?>
```

**CSS**

Style for image blocks.

```
#preview
{
color:#cc0000;
font-size:12px
}
.imgList
{
max-height:150px;
margin-left:5px;
border:1px solid #dedede;
padding:4px;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: It don't have upload progress. Uploading , i can do that.
I want when upload precent gain 100%, all of files were in server.
Currently, when precent gain 100%, it start to moving files to server.